# Inject bean in servlet filter

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, annotations, servlet-filters

Filter class(kotlin)

```
class MyFilter: Filter{
    @Inject
    private lateinit var aService: AService
  
    override fun doFilter(...)
    {.....
        aService.abc()
    }
}
```

Service interface(java)

```
public interface AService{
    void abc();
}
```

Service Implement(kotlin)

```
@Service
class AServiceImpl : AService{
    override fun abc()
        {....}
}
```

Not able to inject the interface in filter. Want to know how to insert with WebApplicationContext or other method as it seems Annotation don't work with filter.

Also, this is application is added as a dependency in other application and there the filter is registered in java configuration. (New to spring boot so maybe missing some simple thing because of which it's not working, any kind help will be of much value).

I was trying using WebApplicationContextUtils but didn't understood what to give in bean name.

Answer (score 0):

`@Inject` (or `@Autowired`) works only for SpringBean classes. You must decorate regular class by some annotation for transforming a regular class to Bean class. In your case use `@Component` above your filter class declaration. Like this:

```
@Component    
class MyFilter: Filter{
```

More info about Spring Beans and Dependency Injection are here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean

Comment: Not working as Annotations doesn't work in servlet filter

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What do you mean with "Annotations doesn't work in servlet filter"?

Comment: This code perfectly works for me:

`@Component
public class Test implements Filter {

 @Inject
 private TestService service;`

Comment: "@Inject" not able to inject the dependency even after using "@Component"